# Which parts of my dataframe are being plotted?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

The goal is to plot the data frame I'm working with on a single chart, with a line for each value of `init_population`  where  the y-axis is `count` and  x-axis is `tick_number`.

I've figured out how to use `groupby()` and `plot()` together to make this: 
[image]

As you can see,  all the lines are there nicely, but I'm pretty confident that the blue at the top that doesn't follow the relationship the other lines are following is actually a different column of data.

So that this is reproducible, the data is available [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O8iG_IbTfT62x-dmE26JpkPJ4Q9FLjHZ).

```
import pandas as pd

max_runs_data = pd.read_csv('clean_table.csv')

del max_runs_data['visualization']

max_runs_data.columns = ['run_number','init_population', 'tick', 'turtle_count']

max_runs_data.set_index('tick', inplace = True)

test_plot_1 = max_runs_data.groupby('init_population')['turtle_count'].plot()


test_plot_2 = max_runs_data.groupby('init_population').plot(y='turtle_count')
```

`test_plot_1` is the linked image, `test_plot_2` is a separate plot for each group.

Is it obvious how to specify the columns for `x` and `y` without losing the grouping on a single chart?

Thanks

Comment: `test_plot_2 = max_runs_data.groupby('init_population').plot(x='turtle_count', y = 'tick')` this line fails for me.

Comment: yeah key error 'tick' ? edited above, actually demonstrates a good point though which is that I have to use `set_index()` to set the x value, rather than doing it by and argument in `plot()`

Comment: Of you want to have it all in one line `max_runs_data.set_index('tick').sort_index().groupby('init_population')['turtle_count'].plot()` but I think it makes sense to split it up to be able to investigate the steps one by one.